# How do I set a cookie on a Wordpress theme template using Javascript/jQuery and then display the cookie value in a different template (if isset)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, cookies

I have a Wordpress website which I set a cookie using the [jQuery cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie).

This is my JS code in the end of one of my wordpress landing pages which sets a cookie using Javascript/jQuery - AND WORKS:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://example.com/wp-content/themes/themeeee-child/js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

// Parse the URL
var getUrlParameter = function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
    var sPageURL = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substring(1)),
        sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
        sParameterName,
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
        sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');

        if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
            return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
};

// Give the URL parameters variable names
var source   = getUrlParameter('utm_source');
var medium   = getUrlParameter('utm_medium');
var term     = getUrlParameter('utm_term');
var content  = getUrlParameter('utm_content');
var campaign = getUrlParameter('utm_campaign');

// Setting Cookie using jQuery 
if(jQuery.cookie('utm_source') == null || jQuery.cookie('utm_source') == "") {
  jQuery.cookie('utm_source', source); 
}
if(jQuery.cookie('utm_medium') == null || jQuery.cookie('utm_medium') == "") {
  jQuery.cookie('utm_medium', medium); 
}
if(jQuery.cookie('utm_campaign') == null || jQuery.cookie('utm_campaign') == "") {
  jQuery.cookie('utm_campaign', campaign); 
}
if(jQuery.cookie('utm_term') == null || jQuery.cookie('utm_term') == "") {
  jQuery.cookie('utm_term', term); 
}
if(jQuery.cookie('utm_content') == null || jQuery.cookie('utm_content') == "") {
  jQuery.cookie('utm_content', content); 
}

// Set a flag 
jQuery.cookie('coo_flag', 1, { expires : 365 }); 


</script>
```

[image]

`$_COOKIE['coo_flag']` is set to "1" now.

On a total different page, at the bottom of the template file, I have this code part that checks using PHP if the `$_COOKIE['coo_flag']` is set, and if is true, it fires a google pixel script:

```
<?php 

  // session_start();
  if ( $_COOKIE["coo_flag"] ) {
    echo $_COOKIE["coo_flag"];
?>

<!-- Google Code for Contact Us Registration Conversion Page -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  /* <![CDATA[ */
  var google_conversion_id = 666;
  var google_conversion_language = "en";
  var google_conversion_format = "3";
  var google_conversion_color = "666";
  var google_conversion_label = "666";
  var google_remarketing_only = false;
  /* ]]> */
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
</script>
<noscript>
<div style="display:inline;">
<img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/666/?label=666&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0"/>
</div>
</noscript>

<?php 
  } else {
    echo "false";
     var_dump($_COOKIE["coo_flag"]);
  }
?>
```

and I keep getting this output result:

> falseNULL

I have been trying to get it using JS too:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://yellowheadinc.com/wp-content/themes/sogo-child/js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var cookieValue = jQuery.cookie("coo_flag");
console.log(cookieValue);

</script>
```

and got no output for `console.log(cookieValue);`

Please help me find the proper way to get the cookie variable.

[01.02.2017]: 
**More enlightenment**:

- A few days after saving the cookie for a year (view screenshot), I noticed it vanished from there (**and I didn't clear my cookies!!!!**).
- Running the page without the "if" statement and just echoing the cookie doesn't work - both on Chrome and Firefox.
- An edit to @**Björn M**:

[image]

Comment: When you say it's on a completely different page, do you mean a different domain?  Cookies can't be used across domains.  I'm guessing not, but figured I'd ask.

Comment: www.example.com/contactus and www.example.com/about - same domain ;)

Comment: I hate to say it but I would put together an even more slimmed down version to test with.  Take out all the HTML code in between your PHP tags and test from there.  If you still can't set a cookie on one page and retrieve on another then there's something else going on with WP cause that's how it should work out of the box.

Comment: Perhaps this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31748884/jquery-cookie-undefined-on-the-line-after-setting-it

Comment: @akousmata I edited the main post. 
I tested all you have suggested and there are no positive results.

Comment: 1) Why do you set the cookie with jQuery instead of PHP? Could you give the details of the set cookie taken from the Developer Console of your browser? 3) Cookies are not only domain, but also possibly path specific.

Comment: 1. When setting this `setcookie("TestCookie", 1, time()+3600, '/');` for example I get this error output: `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/example/public_html/wp-content/themes/theme-new-child/header.php:3) in /home/example/public_html/wp-content/themes/theme-new-child/page-lp.php on line 1708`. 
   -   2. See edited post :)    -    I am exactly testing the path thing, although if you figure i made something wrong with setting it via php i will be happy to know how to set this using PHP rather than loading a JS library. @BjörnM

Comment: 1) See my answer below. You can solve the jQuery problem by giving `/` as the explicit cookie path. 2) I see. You would need to create the cookie inside header.php or switch to `buffered output` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832010/what-is-output-buffering

Comment: @BjörnM 2. For example - adding an 'if' statement in the header "if this is template 'x' => setcoockies(...)" Would that work? Why it doesn't work from within the page? 

I have no idea what's `buffered output` but i will research thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jquery Cookie creates cookies with a path in addition to the domain:

> path
>   path: '/'
>   Define the path where the cookie is valid. By default the path of the cookie is the path of the page where the cookie was created (standard browser behavior). If you want to make it available for instance across the entire domain use path: '/'. Default: path of page where the cookie was created.

A cookie for path /abc is not visible to a page on path /def even though both pathes are on the same domain. Giving the cookie the root path / as quoted above should do the trick.

Comment: Works! The path was the part that was missing. 

Anyway, I will be more than happy if you would maybe know why I kept getting this error saving this coockie with PHP. 
I definitely prefer using PHP rather than loading a whole jQuery cookie library.

Comment: See the comment above. You may not send header fields, e.g. `Cookie: ` after you started serving content, e.g. `<html>`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832010/what-is-output-buffering

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Well maybe output buffering is no good idea in WP after all: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/recommended-php-output-buffering-setting/. Probably you should just move the cookie creation to header.php.

Comment: I have just noticed an other following problem as mentioned before: 
`A few days after saving the cookie for a year (view screenshot), I noticed it vanished from there (and I didn't clear my cookies!!!!).`
I closed the browser and re-opened it - the cookies are gone!

Comment: I guess that the attribute `expires` takes a timestamp or something similiar. If this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14939994/jquery-cookies-set-expire-time does not do the trick please open a new question as it has nothing to do with the path topic. Cheers, mate.